# Write "ANSI" encoded file to disk

Tags: groovy, encoding, cp1252

I am supposed to create an export file using groovy in ANSI format.
When i write the file to disk and open it in "Notepad++" or nano the special characters such as "äüö" are not displayed properly.
Notepad++ displays "Windows-1255" as encoding.

I already tried changing the encoding and additionally converting the string

```
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.io.BufferedWriter
import java.io.InputStream
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets


String fullPath = "/tmp/jamesTempFiles/ansi.txt"

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fullPath), "Cp1252"))
//doesn't work either when i use the following line instead
//BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fullPath), "windows-1252"))
String input = "test\r\näüöß"

writer.write(input)
//doesn't work either when i use the following line instead
//writer.write(new String(input.getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8"))))
writer.close()
```

In Notepad++ the file looks like this
https://pasteboard.co/Inj3SL2.png
The characters in the second line should be those: 
äüöß

Comment: everything is fine in your code. ansii file does not have any marker to detect encoding, so you should do it manually. in notepad++ it's `encodong - charsets - central european - 1250`

Answer (score 0):

I think i may have stumbled over a bug in notepad++.
When changing my test string to actual data notepad++ did start to interpret the special chars as excepted.